# Start Discovery and Start Advertising Timeout not working with Android Nearby

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm working on a project based on Android Nearby. I could add timeouts for operations as Request Connection or Send Payload but it has been impossible to make it works in discovery and advertising process...

```
   Nearby.Connections.startDiscovery(
            googleApiClient,
            getServiceId(),
            object : EndpointDiscoveryCallback() {
                override fun onEndpointFound(endpointId: String, info: DiscoveredEndpointInfo) {
                    Log.d(TAG,
                            String.format(
                                    "onEndpointFound(endpointId=%s, serviceId=%s, endpointName=%s)",
                                    endpointId, info.serviceId, info.endpointName))

                    if (getServiceId() == info.serviceId) {
                        val endpoint = Endpoint(endpointId, info.endpointName)
                        discoveredEndpoints.put(endpointId, endpoint)
                        onEndpointDiscovered(endpoint)
                    }
                }

                override fun onEndpointLost(endpointId: String) {
                    Log.d(TAG, String.format("onEndpointLost(endpointId=%s)", endpointId))
                }
            },
            DiscoveryOptions(STRATEGY))
            .setResultCallback({ status -> onResult(ConnectionCase.START_DISCOVERY, status) }, TIMEOUT_DISCOVERY_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)


 private val TIMEOUT_DISCOVERY_MILLIS: Long = 1000
```

What I pretend with that timeout is to avoid wait ages until the device finds another connection to pair with. Did anybody have that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile the workaround I have implemented is to add a CountDownTimer, with the desired time for the Advertising timeout:

```
private val TIMEOUT_DISCOVERY_MILLIS: Long = 15000
    private val SECOND_MILLIS: Long = 1000
 private fun startConnectionTimer() {

        countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(TIMEOUT_DISCOVERY_MILLIS, SECOND_MILLIS) {

            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                Log.d("ADVERT", "seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / SECOND_MILLIS)
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                if (!connectionAccepted) {
                    onTimeOut()
                }
            }
        }.start()

    }
    //when advertising starts, this function is called:
      protected fun onAdvertisingStarted() {
        connectionAccepted = false
        startConnectionTimer()
    }
//It resets everything and stops the NearbyActions
    fun onTimeOut() {
        resetState()
        stopNearbyActions()
        onTimeOutReached()
        setState(State.UNKNOWN)
    }
```

This way, every time some user loses the connection, he will reach a timeout after 15 seconds.Hope it helps to you all! Waiting for an API better implementation, but it works anyway.